# Executing a QGIS model per feature of a polygon

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have just got into QGIS models and want to run the attached model per feature in a polygon shapefile. I have been trying to do this in two ways and neither of them work. I tried find unique---select the same value---use it to clip but I get an error.

I just want to it to run per feature in the guidelines file and then merge all the final outputs. I also want each file to be the row value. In ArcGIS models it would just be "%FieldName%_SEQ.shp" for example.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Happy to share the test data if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple and in http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/iterative.html

basically just click on the iterate button.[image]

I was thinking of how I would solve it in ArcGIS but QGIS looks at it differently and so I needed to think of it there way.